# Using a JSON Object halting my java servlet

Tags: java, json, servlets

I have a Java application that parses an XML stream from a URL, selects the data that I want, and assembles it in a JSON object. This runs perfectly fine as a Java application, but when I moved it onto a Java servlet, using Tomcat, it will hang at the moment it encounters the declaration of a new JSONObject.`JSONObject temp = new JSONObject();`If I remove any mention of all JSON objects it will run to completion. I have spent a long time trying to find an answer with no luck.
Here is the servlet:

```
public class Servlet extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet {

static ArrayList<String> host_list = new ArrayList<>();
String Host_url = "Sample url";

protected void doPost(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse response) throws javax.servlet.ServletException, IOException {

    doGet(request, response);

}

public void init() throws ServletException
{
    // This function works fine, but logic removed for space
    host_list = ReadFile.get_host_names(file);

}

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                  HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException
{
    // At this point this should print info out to the console.
    Host_Gather.gather(Host_url, host_list);

}

public void destroy()
{

}
```

}

Here is part of the Host_gather class:

```
//By this point the XML has been parsed into various hashtables

 if(clear_flag == true){
        ArrayList<JSONObject> Auth_list = new ArrayList<>();

        Enumeration<String> e2 = Individual_Auth_table.keys();
        while (e2.hasMoreElements()) {
            System.out.println("Will print this");
            JSONObject t = new JSONObject();  //Hangs here
            String key = e2.nextElement();
            t.put("name", key);
            t.put("color", Individual_Auth_table.get(key));
            System.out.println("Never prints this");
            Auth_list.add(t);

        }
        System.out.println("List:" + Auth_list); //Never prints this
```

Tomcat Localhost log:

```
    26-Aug-2015 10:37:36.855 SEVERE [http-apr-8080-exec-9] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log StandardWrapper.Throwable
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/simple/JSONObject
    at com.first.Host_Gather.gather(Host_Gather.java:299)
    at com.first.Servlet.init(Servlet.java:80)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:817)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2503)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2492)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.simple.JSONObject
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1313)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1164)
    ... 22 more

26-Aug-2015 10:37:36.856 SEVERE [http-apr-8080-exec-9] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Allocate exception for servlet Servlet
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.simple.JSONObject
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1313)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1164)
    at com.first.Host_Gather.gather(Host_Gather.java:299)
    at com.first.Servlet.init(Servlet.java:80)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:817)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2503)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2492)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Please post piece of code and tell which library you're using for JSON processing

Comment: Does the code compile ?

Comment: @Olli Zi: Yes the code compiles and runs until it encounters the JSON. If I remove the JSON, it continues past that point and finishes correctly.

Comment: Does your servlet project references the json-API correctly? Take maybe a look in the log directory of your tomcat installation <TOMCAT_HOME>/log.

Comment: @Olli Zi: I looked at the log,posted above, and it appears it is not referencing json correctly. I have the json-simple-1.1.jar in my project, but that must not work for a servlet?

Comment: Is your json*.jar file is located in the WAR-file? Maybe in a lib directory. Take a look:) Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6496560/where-should-i-put-external-jar-files-when-developing-a-web-app

Comment: @Olli Zi: Yes, this appears to have been the solution. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Servlets are by default compiled at runtime.  I suspect that yours is failing to compile on the server.  It's likely that the `JSONObject.java` and its dependencies are not compiled and in your class path on the Tomcat server.